# angular-unknown component of angular material

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm studying angular and I'm startet with the simpliest project that there is in the docs. I receive this error:

'mat-slide-toggle' is not a known element:

1. If 'mat-slide-toggle' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-slide-toggle' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of
   this component to suppress this message.

my html:

```
<mat-slide-toggle>Toggle me!</mat-slide-toggle >
```

my app-module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    MatFormFieldModule,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

where is the problem?

Comment: your HTML template <mat-slide-toggle>Toggle in!</mat-slide-toggle > is in witch module is it also in app-module?

Comment: @RameshKumar I've imported the component in my app module as you can see from code, I should import them in other parts?

Comment: No, just wanted to know that componet and MatSlideToggleModule is in same module. Your HTML is in HomeComponent?

Comment: @RameshKumar yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. I see you have added **MatFormFieldModule** in declarations and exports array. First you have to remove MatFormFieldModule form both declarations and exports, you have to keep it in **imports** array. Second you can use `<mat-slide-toggle>Toggle me!</mat-slide-toggle >` only inside your AppComponent.html file or HomeComponent.html because you have imported **MatSlideToggleModule** in the **appmodule.ts** so `<mat-slide-toggle>Toggle me!</mat-slide-toggle >` only works in the components declared in the appmodule (i.e, in your case AppComponent.html HomeComponent.html)

Hope this helps.
Happy coding :-)